# Webform submission as new node

Tags: nodes, webforms

I have a webform, that the user can fill out. After the user clicks on the "submit" button, a new node should be created with the content the user typed in (text, images, ...). The form itself should be multi-step (first page = personal data, second page = content, etc.). I'm not sure if I can use the regular node creation, because I would need to

1. customize the form
2. the form should be multi-step

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, indeed it is. But could you please tell us why? What's so bad about regular node creation form? It sure sounds as reinventing the wheel, so if you had reasons share them - or we may show you the way that will require a lot of work and fail your needs just as well as current form.

Comment: The idea is, that the enduser that just visits the website should be able to use this form. The form itself should be multi-step (first page = personal data, second page = content, etc.). I'm not sure if I can use the regular node creation - I would need to a) customize the form and b) the form should be multi-step

Comment: Please edit your question instead of providing additional data in comments. Comments should be avoided if possible here. Most people will not read them until they have to anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Webform + Bala's answer is [Multistep Nodeform](https://drupal.org/project/msnf). Using it you can redesign node creation into multistep form and simply allow anonymous to add noeds of given content type.

> For each step you can define which fields should be included in this step. "Fields" includes core-fields like "Title", "Body" or "Authoring information" as well as fields defined by other modules (e.g. Date).

Answer (score 0):

[Webform Default Fields](https://drupal.org/project/webform_default_fields)

> With this module you can easily create much of nodes with same webform
>   fields.
>
> Because you can create more than one webform-enabled content types, you
>   respectively can attach different default fields for each of them.

Comment: Please explain why this module should be helpful. I didn't understand it when you gave the same answer on my question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80022/how-to-create-a-node-with-submissions-of-a-webform either...