# Create drupal node programatically and set custom select list field

Tags: nodes, entities

I have a Drupal 7 node with custom fields. I have no problem setting values to the single text fields but I'm not sure how to set my select list field to one of the allowed keys of the field.

This is the code I've tried to assign the select list to the 'pending' key.

```
$node->field_referee_status['und'][0]['tid'] = 'pending';
```

**Node creation code:**

```
// CREATE NODE
$node = new stdClass;
$node->type = 'referee';
$node->title = 'Referee report for xx';
$node->uid = $user->uid;
$node->status = FALSE;
$node->field_referee_status['und'][0]['tid'] = 'pending';
$node->field_referee_id['und'][0]['value'] = 'test';
$node->field_testff['und'][0]['value'] = "testworked";
node_object_prepare($node);
node_save($node);
```

**Question:** Does anyone know the correct way to assign the key value to a custom select list field when creating Drupal nodes programmatically?

Comment: @sephith, why you dun use webform module. https://www.drupal.org/project/webform much easy to change the setting.

Comment: It is a webform that triggers the node creation. I'm using a node because I get more fine-tuned access to permissions and view manipulation.

Comment: Is it something like this? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80022/how-to-create-a-node-with-submissions-of-a-webform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a select list, you need to store the key value of the custom field.

I just noticed that you're storing taxonomy term reference value, which means you should be storing the ***term ID*** and ***not the actual text value of pending.***

Theres a handy function which allows you to grab the TID based on a term name:

```
$term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name('pending');
$node->field_referee_status[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'] = $term->tid;
```

[See the docs here.](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/7)

**EDIT**

To save into a normal textfield select list:

```
$node->field_referee_status[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'pending';
```

Comment: `taxonomy_get_term_by_name()` returns the term object not the term id.

Comment: apologies, hadn't had my morning coffee when I wrote the answer heh

Comment: Just to clarify - Does taxonomy_get_term_by_name() work on any select list?

Comment: Um, well the function takes any argument you give it, regardless of where it comes from? So you need to make sure that the keys in the select list options contain valid taxonomy term names in this case

Comment: I added TID because I didn't know what else to put. This is an ordinary select list. (My bad) What would I use in its place?

Comment: are you trying to save into a taxonomy term reference field though?

Comment: Negative. I'm trying to save into a regular select list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36108/discussion-between-sephiith-and-alex-kirsten).

Comment: Then, it should be `value` instead of `tid`

Comment: see latest edit, no need for chat. Be clearer with your question next time.